# Outputting post_meta as formatted text

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I had [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107537/output-meta-box-content-as-formatted-text) just yesterday, which I resolved, but it lead me to another problem still. I got the fields using the `wp_editor` to save the content as formatted, but now I can't seem to make it display on the page in the same way.

```
wp_editor(htmlspecialchars_decode($trmet_itinerary) , 'trmet_itinerary', array(
    "media_buttons" => true
    ));
```

is being used to create the wysiwyg editor in my custom Meta Box, which saves good to the database. But it outputs that text to a custom field with markup, which I can't seem to get to display correctly.

For example, entering the following via the admin panel,

> This is the **overview** of content!

outputs, `This is the &lt;strong&gt;overview&lt;/strong&gt; of content!` to it's corresponding custom field.

I've tried variations of `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'trmet_overview', true);?>` to get it to display on the front-end, but nothing does the trick. I know it has something to do with converting the characters and also tried variations of `wpautop` to no avail.

I hope this make sense. **In summary**, I want to output rich text entered in wp admin to the front-end as-is with not just paragraphs or breaks, but all content therein such as `<h1>` tags, bold, italic and the like.

Comment: Well, a full day later and not even an idea on the subject. So, my next option might be to simply use jQuery to find and convert all in-text tags to working ones somehow. So if the output to the site visitor is `This is the <strong>overview</strong> of content!` then I may just use jQuery to wrap that text somehow.

Comment: Not ideal, but I’m using the following until I hear otherwise from a knowledgeable chap: `<script>
// Takes output tags such as <strong> and converts them to HTML
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.parse').each( function() {
 
 orgText = $(this).text();
 newText = orgText.replace();
 $(this).html(newText);
 
 });
});
</script>`